# Eclipse gives error as camera_surface cannot be resolved or is not a field while using R.layout.camera_surface

Tags: android, android-camera

I am trying to access the camera in Android to get the live video. I am trying to set my Content View to `camera_surface`. However, Eclipse gives me error as `camera_surface cannot be resolved or is not a field`

My code is as follows:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.camera_surface);
            surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface_camera);
            surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
            surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
            surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }
```

Could anyone tell what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I needed to create a file called `camera_surface.xml` in the `res->layout` folder and that solved the problem.